# round numbers to non-decimal numbers

Tags: r, numbers, rounding

How can I round the following numbers:

`16554.2644` and `2238.987`

to:

`16550` and `2240`

and

`16560` and `2230`

Thanks

Comment: [R round to nearest .5 or .1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664976/r-round-to-nearest-5-or-1)

Comment: [Rounding numbers to nearest 10 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492836/rounding-numbers-to-nearest-10-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide the number by 10, round using either floor or ceil and then multiply by 10.