# round_any equivalent for dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, rounding, plyr, tidyverse

I am trying to make a switch to the "new" [`tidyverse` ecosystem](http://tidyverse.org/) and try to avoid loading the old packages from Wickham *et al.* I used to rely my coding previously. I found [`round_any`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.4/topics/round_any) function from [plyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html) useful in many cases where I needed custom rounding for plots, tables, etc. E.g.

```
x <- c(1.1, 1.0, 0.99, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001) 

library(plyr)    

round_any(x, 0.1, floor)
# [1] 1.1 1.0 0.9 0.1 0.0 0.0
```

Is there an equivalent for `round_any` function from plyr package in `tidyverse`?

Comment: There isn't, but the function is quite simple, in this case `floor(x / 0.1) * 0.1`. To avoid loading the package, use the `::` notation: `plyr::round_any`.

Comment: It seems that it was replaced by `ggplot2::cut_width`. See https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/releases/tag/v2.0.0

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`ggplot::cut_width` as pointed to in one of the comments, does not even return a numeric vector, but a factor instead. So it is no real substitute.

Since `round` and not `floor` is the default rounding method, a custom replacement until a (dplyr solution may arrive) would be

```
round_any = function(x, accuracy, f=round){f(x/ accuracy) * accuracy}
```

This method could also be used directly from the [plyr](https://github.com/hadley/plyr/blob/34188a04f0e33c4115304cbcf40e5b1c7b85fedf/R/round-any.r#L28-L30) package which contains this implementation. However, be careful when loading `plyr` into a workspace which will cause [naming conflicts when using dplyr](http://krlmlr.github.io/pdlyr/vignettes/pdlyr.html) as well.

Comment: You forgot to tell that you copied [this code literally from the `plyr` package](https://github.com/hadley/plyr/blob/34188a04f0e33c4115304cbcf40e5b1c7b85fedf/R/round-any.r#L28-L30). Of course it's not rocket science, but giving proper attribution is always a good idea. Still voted you up for sharing the simple code. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @MSBerends for pointing out this regretful lack of source attribution. I've added it and also my original thoughts why I did not opt into using `plyr` directly at the time.