# Creating equal and pretty scale breaks with facet_grid()

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I want to create a plot using `facet_grid()`, with free scales for the y axis. However, for each row, the scale breaks should be distributed evenly, that is, with 3 breaks. 
I lended from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436855/change-the-number-of-breaks-using-facet-grid-in-ggplot2), but I was not able to adapt the code in a way that the scale breaks are actually *pretty*.

However, this is my current approach:

```
# Packages
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(scales)


# Test Data
  set.seed(123)

  result_df <- data.frame(
    variable = rep(c(1,2,3,4), each = 4),
    mode     = rep(c(1,2), each = 2),
    treat    = rep(c(1,2)) %>% as.factor(),
    mean     = rnorm(16, mean = .7, sd = 0.2),
    x       = abs(rnorm(16, mean = 0, sd = 0.5))) %>%
    mutate(lower = mean - x,upper = mean + x)

# Function for equal breaks, lended from

  equal_breaks <- function(n = 3, s = 0.05, ...) {
    function(x) {
      d <- s * diff(range(x)) / (1+2*s)
      round(seq(min(x)+d, max(x)-d, length=n), 2)
  }}


  ## Plot

 result_df %>%
   ggplot(aes(y = mean*100, x = treat)) +
   geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = lower*100, ymax = upper*100), shape = 20) +
   facet_grid(variable ~ mode, scales = "free_y")+
   scale_y_continuous(breaks = equal_breaks(n = 3, s = .2))+
   labs(x = "", y = "")
```

Which leads to this [current plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3MQm.png). As one can see, the breaks are far from being reasonable.

Thanks in advance for any kind of recommendation, and please excuse me in case I have missed a already existing solution.

Best, Malte

Comment: Have you looked at the function `axisTicks` ?

Comment: The `equal_breaks()` function has `digits = 2` hard-coded as the second argument of `round()`. If what you want are breaks that are closer to "round" numbers, change this argument to 0 to get the closest integer. Or if you want the nearest multiple of a larger number, say 10, you could replace `round` with `round_any()`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627679/round-any-equivalent-for-dplyr

Comment: Also just to point out, it will not be possible to simultaneously have *exactly* equal locations of the breaks and have very few significant figures in the breaks. You will need slightly uneven breaks if you want "round" numbers with few sig figs.