# How to round integer by intervals of 500 in R

Tags: r

Say I have a vector of integers: `tt <- c(26000L, 26000L, 25333L, 25333L, 25343L, 24667L, 24667L, 24667L, 
23667L)`

I want to replace these integers within the interval of 500 and get:

`26000 26000 25500 25500 25500 25000 25000 25000 24000`

Comment: are you looking for `pretty()` ?

Comment: `500 * ceiling(tt/500)`

Comment: @AndrewGustar Thanks, that works for me.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461209/how-to-round-up-to-the-nearest-10-or-100-or-x

Comment: @MAPK but it doesn't match your desired output.

Comment: @EliKorvigo Sorry I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `round_any` from the `plyr` library.

```
library(plyr)

round_any(as.numeric(tt), 500)
[1] 26000 26000 25500 25500 25500 24500 24500 24500 23500

round_any(as.numeric(tt), 500, f = floor)
[1] 26000 26000 25000 25000 25000 24500 24500 24500 23500

round_any(as.numeric(tt), 500, f = ceiling)
[1] 26000 26000 25500 25500 25500 25000 25000 25000 24000
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your rounding logic, but what about

```
round(as.numeric(tt) / 500) * 500
# [1] 26000 26000 25500 25500 25500 24500 24500 24500 23500
```