# Rounding to the nearest hundredth dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rounding

I am trying to round to the nearest hundredth so that anything above 0.05 and higher rounds up and anything below 0.05 rounds down, so for example I want 0.835 to round to 0.84. I've tried multiple functions such as `plyr::round_any` and functions that were shared on the page below but none of them work as I have intended.

[How to round up to the nearest 10 (or 100 or X)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461209/how-to-round-up-to-the-nearest-10-or-100-or-x)

```
x <- 0.835

round(x, digits = 2)
round_any(x, 0.01, ceiling)
```

Comment: `plyr::round_any(0.835, 0.01, ceiling)` returns 0.84 as expected. Can you show some examples that fail?

Answer (score 0):

Your example does round `0.835` up to `0.84`. You could also use `round_half_up` from `janitor`:

```
janitor::round_half_up(0.835, digits = 2)
[1] 0.84
```